# Redirect old website urls in new GAE/Python/webapp2 website

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, redirect, webapp2

To maintain search engine rankings, I am redirecting the URL paths from the old website (static html) to specified paths in the newly designed website. For example: if the old website contains `/contact-us.html`, the new website should redirect that path to `/contact-us`

My approach involves creating a handler which simply accepts a path and redirects it:

```
# handler redirects URL paths from the old website
class oldPathsHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self, path):

    # dict contains all paths on the old website and their respective directed URLs
    old_paths = dict()

    # example: index.html should redirect to /home
    old_paths['index.html'] = '/home'
    old_paths['contact-us.html'] = '/contact-us'
    old_paths['php_file.php'] = '/phpfile'
    old_paths['pages.html'] = '/pages'
    old_paths['page-1.html'] = '/page/1'

    # redirects to intended path
    self.redirect(old_paths[path])

# routing
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', Home),
  ('/(.+)/?', oldPathsHandler),
  ('/get/something', AnotherHandler)
], debug = True)
```

With this approach, the old links indeed are redirected to the new paths. However, the problem is that other URLs which should not be redirected are also redirected. The path `/get/something` above will be redirected to `/`.

The solution to this should exist in the Regular Expression inside the routing configuration. I am a novice at RE, so I would appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the rules and you should be fine. Later on, when you'll see that nobody is actually visiting the old URLs you could just delete this handler.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', Home),
  ('/get/something', AnotherHandler),
  ('/(.+)/?', oldPathsHandler),
], debug = True)
```